# GDB set a breakpoint at a wrong address for a template function

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

When I set a breakpoint in a specific template function in GDB, it shows 3 different breakpoints set (I guess this is due to template nature of the function). The addresses of 2 of them looks correct, but one is something like 0x00...0013. As a result, GDB can't continue, it complaints about wrong address. What does it mean and what can I do about it? 
Not sure if this matters, but I set the breakpoint like this: b file_name.cc:line_number .
I can set a bp successfully at another template function located in a different directory.

Comment: Similar, but still does not answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666767/gdb-error-setting-break-point-in-template-class-functions-in-header-files?rq=1

Comment: How did you set a breakpoint? See this: http://tdistler.com/2008/11/13/debugging-c-templates-brekpoints-and-gdb

Comment: @dbrank0  Thanks, it's interesting, I'll try it.